# JavaScript Freezes Browser While Function Is Executing

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a web page which acts as a database querying tool. The database table is quite large (26MB) in size so I have decided to store each row from the table as a JavaScipt object in an array (to prevent continuous transmission of data).

The page loads with no problems. The trouble begins when I begin to 'query' the array of JavaScript objects.

The function below executes on the keyup event of a HTML text box. When this function executes it causes the browser to become unresponsive and freeze temporarily until the function has finished executing. I have previously read on the use of the setTimeout() and setInterval() functions to overcome this problem but I have been unable to adapt these to my own problem.

```
function searchStock() {
    results.innerHTML = "Stock Loading..."; //results is a div tag where query results are displayed
    var stringTyped = nameTextBox.value;
    var resultString = "<table>";
    for (var z = 0; z < stock.length; z++) //stock is the array of objects to be searched
    {
        if (stringTyped == "") {
            resultString = resultString + rows[z]; //rows is an array consisting of how each item in the stock is displayed
        }
        else {
            if (stock[z].Stock_Name.indexOf(stringTyped) != -1) {
                resultString = resultString + rows[z];
            }
        }
    }
    resultString = resultString + "</table>";
    results.innerHTML = resultString;
}​
```

Comment: It's freezing because every keyup it is querying 26mb of data, just because you make the user load the data at the start doesn't make it easier to get the specific data they need. You are making the client pc do the bulk of the work rather than your web server, which isn't really recommended as you will get freezes as it does the work.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andy. I'm aware the volume of data is the cause of the problem. I'm looking for help to 'multithread' (for want of a better word - as JavaScript does no such thing) to stop the page freezing. As I mentioned in my question, people have previously used setInterval() and setTimeout() to overcome the freezing problem.

Comment: This could be passed to a Web Worker (which is a separate thread), but you would still have a delay in response - just not the UI freezing.

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb, thats exactly what I'm looking for. Can you recommend any good tutorials on Web Workers please?

Comment: I don't know good tutorials, but here's a gist: http://jsfiddle.net/2uUEM/ (works on Chrome). It builds an array of length 10000000 and then filters out the even numbers, just so that it takes a while. You can see that the UI continues to respond during the calculations.

Comment: Another thing you could do is if you have to execute some other part of program or anything else, you could use callbacks for this and utilize this time for performing other functionality. As mentioned above It is better to use web server .Also Web Worker will have delay.